Latest zombienet and polkadot sdk parachain node produce only 3 blocks on parachain side
https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/717bbb24c40717e70d2e3b648bcd372559c71bd2/templates/parachain/README.md
Latest zombienet and polkadot sdk parachain node produce only 3 blocks on parachain side.
cargo build --locked --profile=testnet --features fast-runtime --bin polkadot --bin polkadot-prepare-worker --bin polkadot-execute-worker




Latest zombienet + polkadotsdk works only if you add one extra relaychain nodes
export PATH=$PATH:polkadot-source-code-folder/testnet/release/
cargo build --locked --release --features fast-runtime --bin polkadot --bin polkadot-prepare-worker --bin polkadot-execute-worker
[[relaychain.nodes]]
name = "bob"
validator = true
ws_port = 9999

so template/parachain/zombienet.toml looks like:
[relaychain]
default_command = "polkadot"
chain = "dev"

[[relaychain.nodes]]
name = "alice"
validator = true
ws_port = 9944

[[relaychain.nodes]]
name = "bob"
validator = true
ws_port = 9999

[[parachains]]
id = 1000

[parachains.collator]
name = "alice"
ws_port = 9988
command = "parachain-template-node"

